# Upgrading Docker on Windows container at Azure

Tags: azure, docker

How do we upgrade Docker on the "Windows Server 2016 Datacenter - with Containers" Compute image?  Currently it is "1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta, build 050b611".  I would like to get it to 1.13

Thanks

Comment: update docker extension on the vm?

Comment: Yes.  On the host.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted.  Thanks to evgenyl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [this post](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-upgrade-to-docker-v1-13-on-windows-server-2016/27624/2):

```
Stop-Service docker
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $Env:programdata\docker
Invoke-WebRequest https://get.docker.com/builds/Windows/x86_64/docker-1.13.0.zip -UseBasicParsing -OutFile docker.zip
Expand-Archive docker.zip -DestinationPath $Env:ProgramFiles
Remove-Item -Force docker.zip
Start-Service docker
```

Comment: Thank you!!  This seemed to work I just updated to latest zip docker-1.13.1.zip